# Launcher Activity overlaps notification tap activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I have implemented notification in android application, Everything is working as expected. I am getting one problem to open activity after tapping on notification or action button from the notification.

Process:

1. Kill the application instance from the background that means application should not run in the background.
2. Send the notification from the FCM, Tap or click on the action from the notification. Open the activity named "B". In application, there is one Main activity + Splash activity which loads when the application is getting started fresh (Application was not running in the background).

Problem: When the application is not running in the background. If I click on the notification, I can see that Activity "B" opens but overlap by my Splash+Main Activity. If I press back from the main activity then I can see my activity B. I am not able to find any lead or solution from the internet. In short, when application is not active in the background in that case my launcher activity (main+splash) and Activity B both are trying to start together and main activity starts late as it's checking some login/authentication/session related things.

What is the solution in this case?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

```
  Intent defaultClickIntent = new Intent(context, B.class);     
      defaultClickIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP     | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);     
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, defaultClickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Seem you not have `click_action: activityB` in your FCM message? So you need to handle by hand when click `notification` on `onNewIntent`  by `getIntent().getExtras()` to start `activityB` and finish `main+splash`.

Comment: - Set activity B as pending intent and set Extras to check if it came
   from notification click or not.
 - If that opens from notification click than just finish activity B and open MainActivity.

Comment: @MayankPandya I guess you misunderstood the question. I want to open Activity B from the notification click.

Comment: @JohnSteve I have set up PendingIntent in the click_action. Actually, activity B is opened but MainActivity overlaps it. So are you saying to open MainActivity with extras and based on extras decide to open activity B ?

Comment: As I see in your code, your `intent` is an `implicit intent`, it does not point to your `ActivityB` class. try `Intent defaultClickIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);`

Comment: I forgot to add that thing in the edited part, actually, I have this in my code already. Updated question.